# Using threads to break out of game loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a console game in Java that has 10 rounds that are 2 minutes each.  I need a way to use threads to alert the user every 30 seconds that have passed and then override the main method and break the user out of the game loop after two minutes have passed.

How could I use threads to break the main loop out of one function and return the user to another one?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do it in the way you're describing.

Comment: @Joe C Thanks, and sorry if this wasn't a good question or whatever.  How would you suggest pulling the user out of the game loop after two minutes?

Comment: Use `break` with a label to literally break out of a long or nested loop: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html  Or you can set a flag and exit the loop by testing the flag once each iteration.

Comment: Consider running the round in a separate thread, and interrupt said thread after two minutes.

Comment: In actual game programming, you call a routine or method that does not wait.  If you're waiting on user input now, I don't see a problem with waiting longer: how do you do anything else right now, other than wait on user input?  It seems like your game should be the type to not care about waiting, or you've designed yourself into a corner that you won't be able fix.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I can't figure out how to stop a thread if it is waiting for user input.

Comment: Markspace, the problem is that I want the user to have a limited amount of time to think of how they will respond to the simulation.  How would you call a method that does not wait for input?

Comment: For comparison, look at this example of actual Java game code: https://www.lwjgl.org/guide  Notice they use a game loop, and poll (rather than wait) on user input. `while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) ) {.../* Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be// invoked during this call. */ glfwPollEvents(); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use non blocking API (that give you for example the current state of the keyboard/mouse rather than block) in a loop and just not run the next iteration when the time out occured.

Or you can interrupt the thread if this one is blocked/sleeping on a blocking API calling this the interupt method of that thread:

```
refToThreadToInterupt.interupt();
```

This will generate an InteruptedException if the thread is blocked or set the interupt flag to true otherwise. Can be checked by the thread with:

```
refToThreadToInterup.isInterupted();
```

As you have no idea as of what the thread is doing when you interupt it, you don't know if you get the exception or if the boolean will just be set to true, so you have to deal with both cases.